# How do I log in using facebook PHP SDK without having to re-authenticate?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am basically building a blog-style application which will post to a facebook page a  link and a description whenever a new post is made. Users will not login to the application, so it shouldn't ask the individual posters for their facebook credentials.

I am using the Facebook Version 5 PHP SDK

Basically, the simplest way would be to have it always use my account's access token to obtain the page access token and post as the page every time someone makes a post.

I understand how to do this handoff of tokens and to post as the page, but I don't know how to always obtain the access token for my account to make this transaction without there being an additional step of following a callback url after each post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if i understand what you are trying to do, you should not let other users post something on your Page with your Page Token - but there IS an Extended Page Token, and it is valid forever so you could just store it.

More information on Tokens and how to generate them:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/